# Integrals in Julia with multiple functions

Tags: julia, symbolic-math, numerical-integration

I am new to Julia and I have a code:

```
using Symbolics, QuadGK,  SymbolicNumericIntegration

@variables M, m_0, ξ, ϵ_σ, ϵ_r, R̃, ε, U_λ, α,  β,v, λ, _ξ_, λ_c,φ
####################################

R̃ = ε^2 - U_λ - α * (α + 2*ε*λ*ϵ_σ)/ξ^2
X(ξ, ε, λ, α) = quadgk(_ξ_-> (λ + (α*ε)/(1-2/_ξ_))/( ( (α^2)/(1-2/_ξ_) + _ξ_^2  ) * sqrt(ε^2 - (1-2/_ξ_)*(1+λ^2/_ξ_^2) - (α^2+2*ε*λ*α)/(_ξ_^2)) ), ξ, Inf, rtol = 1e-5)[1] 
S(ξ, ε, λ, α, ϵ_σ,φ)  = exp(-(ε+ϵ_σ*v*sqrt(ε^2-1)*sin( (-X(ξ,ε, λ, α))*(φ-ϵ_σ*ϵ_r)))*(β)/sqrt(1-v^2) )[1]

print(integrate(ε*exp(-(ε+ϵ_σ*v*sqrt(ε^2-1)*sin( (-X(ξ,ε, λ, α))*(φ-ϵ_σ*ϵ_r)))*(β)/sqrt(1-v^2) )),(λ,0,10))
```

and the last function (`integrate`) gives me an error:

```
ERROR: LoadError: MethodError: no method matching kronrod(::Type{Num}, ::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  kronrod(::Any, ::Integer, ::Real, ::Real; rtol, quad) at ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/weightedgauss.jl:90
  kronrod(::Type{T}, ::Integer) where T<:AbstractFloat at ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/gausskronrod.jl:318
  kronrod(::Integer, ::Real, ::Real) at ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/gausskronrod.jl:343
  ...
Stacktrace:
  [1] macro expansion
    @ ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/gausskronrod.jl:566 [inlined]
  [2] _cachedrule
    @ ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/gausskronrod.jl:566 [inlined]
  [3] cachedrule
    @ ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/gausskronrod.jl:571 [inlined]
  [4] do_quadgk(f::var"#1#2"{Num, Num, Num}, s::Tuple{Num, Num}, n::Int64, atol::Nothing, rtol::Float64, maxevals::Int64, nrm::typeof(LinearAlgebra.norm), segbuf::Nothing)
    @ QuadGK ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/adapt.jl:7
  [5] (::QuadGK.var"#50#51"{Nothing, Float64, Int64, Int64, typeof(LinearAlgebra.norm), Nothing})(f::Function, s::Tuple{Num, Num}, #unused#::Function)
    @ QuadGK ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/adapt.jl:235
  [6] handle_infinities(workfunc::QuadGK.var"#50#51"{Nothing, Float64, Int64, Int64, typeof(LinearAlgebra.norm), Nothing}, f::var"#1#2"{Num, Num, Num}, s::Tuple{Num, Num})
    @ QuadGK ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/adapt.jl:134
  [7] quadgk(::Function, ::Num, ::Vararg{Num}; atol::Nothing, rtol::Float64, maxevals::Int64, order::Int64, norm::Function, segbuf::Nothing)
    @ QuadGK ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/adapt.jl:234
  [8] quadgk(::Function, ::Num, ::Vararg{Any}; kws::Base.Pairs{Symbol, Float64, Tuple{Symbol}, NamedTuple{(:rtol,), Tuple{Float64}}})
    @ QuadGK ~/.julia/packages/QuadGK/ZWSGN/src/adapt.jl:229
  [9] X(ξ::Num, ε::Num, λ::Num, α::Num)
    @ Main ~/czarne_dziury.jl:8
 [10] top-level scope
    @ ~/czarne_dziury.jl:18
```

I tried to calculate this integral with QuadGK but it also didn't work. Cubature and HCubature are also giving errors. I know that this integral is complicated but is it really too complicated for Julia? I hope that there is solution to this problem and the reason why errors apears is because I lack in programming skills

Comment: Interesting problem, to debug problems like this, my advice is to start with a simpler version of the problem and try to get it working. If it still doesn't work, keep making it simpler until you have the simplest possible example. Once you get something working, then go in the other direction, making it more complex until you get back to the full problem.

Comment: QuadGK is for numerical integration, it won't do symbolic integration